# Amazon Cognito with Unity - CognitoAWSCredentials NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine

So, I'm using this example code here: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-unity-samples/blob/master/Cognito%20Sync/CognitoSyncManagerSample.cs

But I keep getting the error NullReferenceException on line 59, whenever this code is run:

```
_credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(IdentityPoolId, _Region);
```

I have properly set the Identity Pool ID given to me by the Amazon Cognito identity pool that I created online, and the region is also properly set.

My Unity version is 2017.1.0f3 and the AWS SDK version is 3.3.187.0. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Edit: This is the stack trace: https://pastebin.com/wmhaYE37

Comment: Is that line 59? What's the stack trace?

Comment: @Blorgbeard It finally worked, although it only worked when I started a new project and only imported the CognitoSync package. Maybe there were problems when I imported the other packages too, I'm not sure. The packages I'm using with Cognito are DynamoDB, IdentityMgmt, Lambda, Mobile Analytics, S3, Simple Email, and Simple Notification. I'm gonna do more testing to figure out what caused the problem. For now, I'm updating my question with the stack trace.